# Gulp not outputing anything

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, postcss

I am running the following in my gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  var processors = [
    csswring
  ];

  return gulp.src('xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/paws2play/sass/style.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .on('error', sass.logError)
      .pipe(postcss(processors))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/paws2play/style.css'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', function(){
  gulp.watch('**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

After running gulp styles I get this out put

```
[19:05:34] Using gulpfile c:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\paws2play\gulpfile.js
[19:05:34] Starting 'styles'...
[19:05:34] Finished 'styles' after 17 ms
```

When I go and check my style.css file, it is empty. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have run sass -trace --watch style.scss:style.css and it worked just fine. I am at a loss for what to do here?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I see a little error, but I don't think it's a problem in your case.

First make sure that your path is correct.

- Check where is your `gulpfile.js` located
- If it is in `xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content`, then find `PATH` in `gulpfile.js` below and change with `./themes/paws2play`

Then change your `gulpfile.js` with:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  var processors = [
    csswring
  ];

  return gulp.src('PATH/sass/style.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(postcss(processors))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('PATH'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', function(){
  gulp.watch('PATH/sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

You can also add [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to see files that are in your stream.